# Fit to frame with vertical justification options

Tags: scripting, adobe-indesign, extendscript

Working with InDesign script I am using

```js
TF.fit(FitOptions.frameToContent).  //TF as a textFrame
```

to fit the content into the textframe and remove the extra space

But when I have a condition for vertical justification options set to `Align: Bottom` i am not able to fit the content.

Assuming this to be my TextFrame (Image 1)

[image]

Here are the properties of the text frame (Image 2)

[image]

When I do `FitOptions.frameToContent` i get this (Image 3)

[image]

But when the text frame has the align property set to the bottom I want this to fit it like this(this was achieved by double-clicking on the top center alignment as shown in the red indicator below. (Image 4) (Image 5)

[image]

[image]

I tried all the available options at http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs4js/pe_FitOptions.html but I had no luck making it work. Please help me to achieve the same using scripting.

Cross-reference: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/fit-to-frame-with-vertical-justification-options/td-p/11120458?page=1

================== First try ==================

```
var tf = app.selection[0];
var tfp = tf.textFramePreferences;
tfp.autoSizingReferencePoint = AutoSizingReferenceEnum.BOTTOM_CENTER_POINT;
tfp.autoSizingType = AutoSizingTypeEnum.HEIGHT_ONLY;
tf.fit(FitOptions.frameToContent)
```

This still gives me the same result(image 3) but expected result is image 4.

================== Second try ==================

This is the auto-sizing property.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This command indeed seems to work only with the top edge as a reference point, just as it does in the UI (if you actually use the menu command, not clicking any borders).

What you could do to work around this, is to temporarily enable auto-sizing (height only) and setting the reference point for auto-sizing to the bottom:

```js
var tf = app.selection[0];
var tfp = tf.textFramePreferences;
tfp.autoSizingReferencePoint = AutoSizingReferenceEnum.BOTTOM_CENTER_POINT;
tfp.autoSizingType = AutoSizingTypeEnum.HEIGHT_ONLY;
tfp.autoSizingType = AutoSizingTypeEnum.OFF;
```

Note, the last line turns off the auto sizing again and is optional; if you don't mind that the frame keeps auto sizing you don't need to turn it off.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any impact on the result - updated question on what i tried.

Comment: That's strange. This sequence of commands results exactly in the result shown in image 4 for me. Tried this in InDesign CS6, but I wouldn't expect this to work any differently in InDesign CC. Just for the record: You would *not* need that `tf.fit()` line, as the other commands should give the correct result (but I guess the skipping `tf.fit()` line would also not change the outcome much for you...)

Comment: Why should I not be using .fit()? as I am trying to fit the content to the text frame correct?

Comment: Because in this case the auto sizing takes care of fitting the frame to the content (see the Auto-Size feature in the Text Frame Options dialog), so there's no need to use the text frame options here. What is you result if you skip the tf.fit command?

Comment: It's just the same and nothing changed. if you need any more properties on the text frames please let me know.

Comment: Ok, just tested it in ID 2020, works just fine. Can you test two things for me: A) Run the script without the last line (the one turning auto sizing off again), then go to the Text Frame Options and check, if Auto Sizing is actually turned on. B) If it's not, can you check what happens if you turn on Auto Sizing manually. Does that actually work?

Comment: Tried and attached the property panel, Isn't it supposed to be `TOP_CENTER_POINT` as what I asked earlier in the question, Even that isn't working for me.

Comment: Does turning on the the auto-sizing manually by clicking on the bottom center arrow actually work? I don't quite understand why there is no activated arrow in your screenshot. Usually one of the 9 arrows should be slightly hightlighted to indicate that it is activated.